# Historically, did the sanskrit varnamala contain two 'la' vyanjan varnas?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit, tantra

Historically, did the sanskrit varnamala contain two 'la' vyanjan varnas?
It seems there was one in the 'ya' varga and another one in the 'sha' varga.

Current texts on sanskrit or hindi grammar and wikipedia show a varnamala  with but one 'la'. However I have found differing configurations of the Rashi, Nakshatra and Kulakul chakras in different translations [1](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.338822/page/n41/mode/2up) [2](https://archive.org/details/BrihatTantraSaraPartIKapildevNarayan/page/n39/mode/2up) of the Brhat Tantrasaara and also in blogs(https://shubhamalock.com/remedies/mantra-suitability/).

Comment: This isn't a question about Hinduism

Comment: I hope the edited information puts this question within the purview of this site.

Comment: https://history.stackexchange.com/ this is isn't about religion it is more about history and language. You should ask this question in history SE

Comment: I'm asking because there are discrepancies in the two translations and the blog post I've linked to and I find that the correct alphabetical arrangement is required to determine what it should be. The end goal is to determine the accurate translation of the section on mantra compatibility from the Brihat tantrasara, which is a shakta text focused on spiritual pursuits. Therefore I request that this be considered a question on scripture.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. I have upvoted your question

Comment: Panini missed one for all those who vote close BG vibuthi adhyaya says he is venjana  so each letter is epithet of god any statement can be misinterpreted missing one la which panini did samuldamashya pamsure is one example

Comment: @PrasannaR I missed your comment earlier. Can you add some more details about this "samuldamashya pamsure"

Comment: It's in vishnu suktha of rig veda I believe describing universe as speck of dust in the foot finger of lord

Comment: @PrasannaR Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ल and ळ were used in Vedic Sanskrit, but the latter is absent in classical Sanskrit as codified by Panini and later grammarians. It is still present in the daughter language Marathi.

[Source](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38375/historically-did-the-sanskrit-alphabet-contain-two-la-consonants)